# load content into div using usual jquery and deeplinking

Tags: jquery, html

I'm not a programmer, I am primarily a designer, so I've got some difficulties in developing certain things.

I've got a doubt on how to use deep link and asual jquery (or other plugin more suitable) in the following scenario.

The nav structure is more or like:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/pt/empresa/historia" title="História">História</a></li>
<li><a href="/pt/empresa/historia/missao" title="Missão">Missão</a></li>
<li><a href="/pt/empresa/historia/universo" title="Universo">Universo</a></li>
<li><a href="/pt/empresa/historia/numeros" title="números">números</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the div

```
<div id="content-mask">
<div id="content-container">
</div>
</div>
```

I want to load into content-container the content of the content-container in the page of the clicked link.

Comment: I am not getting the scenario, can you please explain with more details.. What I understand is do you want to load content in "content-container" when you click on link???

Comment: @HirenSoni yes, each link in the ul list corresponds to other asp or html page. 
Each time that someone clicks a link the content of the div in that page is loaded to the content-container on the main page. 
Also I would like to deeplink. 
I'm in circles with asual jquery address but I can´t find a way to make this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

first add `id` tag to `ul`:

```
<ul id="myList">
```

then:

```
$("ul#myList li a").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url : $(this).attr("href"),
      success:function(data){
         $("#content-container").html($(data).find("#content-container").html());
      }
   })
  return false;
})
```

Comment: I haven't actually tested that, but I essentially wrote the same thing. The only suggestion I have is for the original poster to provide a unique ID on the list and use that as the selector (e.g.,) <ul id="myList"> and then replace the jQuery selector with $("#myList").

Comment: Many thanks, but how can I make it deeplink?
So that the if I enter in the addressbar, for instance, www.site.com/pt/empresa/historia, it would load the content in the div of the associated file?
Also how can I change the title?
Many, many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `load` method:

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul li a').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault() // prevents the default action of the click event
       $('.content-container').load(this.href) // loads the content based on the value of href attribute 
       // or $('.content-container').load(this.href + " .content-container") in case that I have misunderstood your question
    })
})
```

- [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

<sub>Please note that you should have only one element with class of `content-container` otherwise you have duplicate contents.</sub>

Comment: Many thanks, but how can I make it deeplink?
So that the if I enter in the addressbar, for instance, www.site.com/pt/empresa/historia, it would load the content in the div of the associated file?
Also how can I change the title?
Many, many thanks

Comment: @user1463905   
@user1463905 You are welcome, JavaScript has no control on address bar when that you type an address and hit the enter key, what do exactly do you mean? if you want to change the title of the page you can code `$('title').text('new title')`

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a span tag like so: (You can also use a div tag as well if you needed, same kind of code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  div { color:blue; }
  span { color:red; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    The values stored were 
    <span></span>
    and
    <span></span>
  </div>
<script>var div = $("div")[0];
    jQuery.data(div, "test", { first: 16, last: "pizza!" });
    $("span:first").text(jQuery.data(div, "test").first);
    $("span:last").text(jQuery.data(div, "test").last);</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

**As OP Stated in his comment below:**

> how can I make it deeplink? So that the if I enter in the addressbar, for instance, www.site.com/pt/empresa/historia, it would load the content in the div of the associated file?

**Solution:**

```
$("ul li a").click(function(e){           

    // Include your domain address in a URL string with anchor's href
    var url = "http://www.your-website-address.com/" + $(this).attr('href')

    $('#content-container').html("Loading Please Wait");
    $('#content-container').load(url);    
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

**Additional Notes:**

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

### [A WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/brHSk/)

**OLD:**

Use jQuery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to achieve this.

```
$("ul li a").click(function(e){           
    $('#content-container').html("Loading Please Wait");
    $('#content-container').load(this.href);    
    e.preventDefault(); 
})​;
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/aUSeA/)

Comment: Many thanks, but how can I make it deeplink?
So that the if I enter in the addressbar, for instance, www.site.com/pt/empresa/historia, it would load the content in the div of the associated file?
Also how can I change the title?
Many, many thanks

Comment: @user1463905: Please see my updated my answer for your question. And Which title you want to change?

Comment: many many thanks, but I think deeplink doesn't work. 
Have you already worked with asual address or history.js?